# Understanding half sibling test report

Tags: dna, half-siblings

I had requested DNA analysis of my half sibling and have received the results.

But unfortunately I am confused with results of the conclusion, meaning the conclusion which is in bold and the sentence below seems to me a contradictory statement.

Can you help me to  understand the conclusion  as much as possible?

CONCLUSION

> **The DNA result provide weak support for me and my sis are being related as a half sibling, having one parent in common.**

> It is 3.3 times more likely that me and my sis are related as half sibling than if they are unrelated.

Comment: Which company did you take your test with?

Comment: The "3.3 times" is saying there's a 76% chance you are half siblings and a 24% chance you have some other relationship.

Answer (score 2):

There's no contradiction.

It's 3.3 times more likely that you and your sister are half-siblings than not.

Which is not as strong support as it would be if (for example) it was 100 times more likely that you and your sister are half-siblings than not.

If you want to investigate your degree of relatedness further, you could both do autosomal DNA tests with (for example Ancestry.co.uk) and persuade your shared and unshared parents to do the same if you know them and can do so. This would probably have been a better option to start with, rather than buying a very specific test that has left you with more questions than it answered.  Unless of course you needed it for legal reasons, which seems unlikely.